# How can I open ports on my Linksys RV082 router?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I bought a Linksys RV082 small business router. It's a nice 8-port wired router with a lot of configuration options, and so far it's working pretty well.

One of my computers on the LAN is a server running various applications on different ports. I can access all of these applications by going to `192.168.1.100:PORT`; however, when I try to access it using the remote IP address, it times out. I've tried out a couple of websites that check to see if your ports are open, and they all say "no."

However... I *did* open the necessary ports. Or at least I thought I did. Here's some screenshots of what I've tried so far (I've tried both Port Forwarding and UPnP.)

[image]
[image]

What am I missing? How do I open ports on this router?

Comment: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/RV082/defaultguide.htm

Comment: @DavidPostill - thanks for the guide, but that describes exactly what I've already done. The reason I'm posting this question is because that didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible that you haven't enabled the Jira port mapping. Without a screenshot showing the Jira mapping selected (highlighted), this version of the Linksys software doesn't let you know. (If you highlight the mapping you get to see the [] enabled checkbox ticked - or not.)

Comment: Yes, I have of course had it enabled all along: http://i.imgur.com/BUGXK7x.png

Comment: I took "I did open the necessary ports. Or at least I thought I did" to mean that you sought confirmation. Without a screenshot illustrating the checkbox ticked it wasn't possible to know for certain that you had followed all the necessary steps.

Comment: That's fair. If only it were that easy! I'm all out of ideas at this point because I've followed just about every step that the different guides recommend.

Comment: I've previously had problems with Linksys RV052 devices and the firewall which were resolved by upgrading to the latest firmware. (Even for a new device this isn't necessarily what's shipped.)

Unfortunately I can't see any reference to Port Forwarding in the firmware release notes at <https://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=282414011&softwareid=282465789&release=4.2.1.02>